# Is possible to initialize an object in javascript in this way?

Tags: javascript, object, initialization

I'd like to initialize an object in javascript calling directly a method that belongs to it:

```
  var obj = (function(){
      return{
          init: function(){
              console.log("initialized!");
              return this;
          },
          uninit: function(x){
              console.log("uninitialized!");
          }
      };
  }).init();

  //later
  obj.uninit();
  obj.init();
```

This specific example doesn't work, is there something similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: `init()` returns `this`, thanks Guffa.

You're only defining an anonymous function, but not actually calling it. To call it right away, add a pair of parentheses:

```
var obj = (function(){
  return{
      init: function(){
          console.log("initialized!");
          return this;
      },
      uninit: function(x){
          console.log("uninitialized!");
      }
  };
})().init();
```

Comment: Also, the `init` function needs to return `this` so that there is something to put in the `obj` variable.

Comment: Right, thanks for the clarification Guffa, I've edited my question.

Comment: In this case 'var obj =' is not really necessary, is it?

Comment: as I see it is already global variable and not necessary here to define var.But if you dont define var in a function, it will be defined in global context so things can go wrong.

Comment: @Kooilnc: here *var obj =* is necessary to get obj reference, so we can call it later.